# Bind textblock visibility with custom property of grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, attached-properties

**Hello,**

After reading lots of topics about visibility binding for hours, I'm asking here because I don't manage to make my case works.

I have a grid with a custom attached property (type System.Windows.Visibily) which I want to use to display (or not) a textblock inside the grid (by binding). Also I want to change the visibility everytime the custom attached property change.

**What I have done so far :
CustomProperties class :**

```
    public static class CustomProperties
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty starVisibilityProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("starVisibility", 
            typeof(System.Windows.Visibility), typeof(CustomProperties), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        public static System.Windows.Visibility GetStarVisibility(UIElement element)
        {
            if (element == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            return (System.Windows.Visibility)element.GetValue(starVisibilityProperty);
        }

        public static void SetStarVisibility(UIElement element, System.Windows.Visibility value)
        {
            if (element == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
            element.SetValue(starVisibilityProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

**Then here is my xaml :**

```
            <Grid Name="server1State" Grid.Row="1" local:CustomProperties.StarVisibility="Hidden">
                <TextBlock Name="server1Star" Text="&#xf005;" FontFamily="{StaticResource fa-solid}" FontSize="30" Margin="10" Foreground="#375D81" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=server1State, Path=server1State.(local:CustomProperties.starVisibility)}"/>
            </Grid>
```

But when I run my app, the textblock is absolutely not hidden, this is visible, and never change. I have tried lots of things with Path and also INotifyPropertyChanged but as I am working with static custom attached property, I didn't manage to make it works.

Maybe some of you could help me, **thanks**.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using a custom property rather than a converter?  Also, why is the property on the Grid rather than the textbox?

Comment: My custom property was first a boolean, which i wanted to convert as visibility with BooleanToVisibilityConverter during binding, but as I didn't find how to make it works, I tried to remove the "convertion step". But of course i would prefer to have a boolean. 
And I would like to have a property on the grid because later i will have many things inside the grid that could change according to the property value. It will become a "state property" which will be converted will converters.

Comment: I presume you're using MVVM, if so, why don't you instead expose a collection of properties for the various states of visibility e.g. presuming you've got a deadline, invoice status, and accepted status - IsEditable, IsPassedDeadline, and IsAccepted.  Then  do your business logic in the VM rather than a custom property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Binding.Path` on the `TextBlock` is wrong.

Since I've read from your comment, that you prefer to use a boolean property, I'll show how to convert the `bool` value to a `Visibility` enumeration value using the library's [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?view=netframework-4.8).
I think you may already got it, but then got confused due to your wrong `Binding.Path`:

**CustomProperties.cs**

```
public class CustomProperties : DependencyObject
{
  #region IsStarVisibile attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsStarVisibileProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IsStarVisibile",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(CustomProperties),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

  public static void SetIsStarVisibile(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value) => attachingElement.SetValue(CustomProperties.IsStarVisibileProperty, value);

  public static bool GetIsStarVisibile(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (bool)attachingElement.GetValue(CustomProperties.IsStarVisibileProperty);

  #endregion
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid Name="Server1StateGrid"
        CustomProperties.IsStarVisibile="False">
    <TextBlock Text="&#xf005;" 
               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Server1StateGrid,       
                            Path=(CustomProperties.IsStarVisibile), 
                            Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer !! I still have an error but I think we almost got it because I have never faced this one : when i want to run the app, it fails with "XamlParseException" => "Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '88' and line position '149". It occurs when i add Path and Converter

Comment: It fails when i add Path, moreover i had to write "(local:CustomProperties.IsStarVisible)"

Comment: Yes, the example is supposed to be generic. Namespaces are specific. So I left the namespaces. Of course you have to qualify _each_ type used in XAML, so that the XAML parser can resolve the types. Regarding the error, have you added the `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` to any `ResourceDictionary` within the scope? The example is definitely working.

Comment: Yes inside Window.Resources as you did. The following compiles well "{Binding ElementName=server1State, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}", it only fails when I try to add Path.

Comment: Does your attached property implementation of `CustomProperties.IsStarVisibile` looks exactly like mine?

Comment: Can you please just copy my above code into a clean `Window` file and run it? I've just tested it and it works.

Comment: It works !! Finally !! As you suggested, I tried to run your code in a clean Window without modifying it (a simple copy paste) and it worked well. I probably failed when adapting it to my case because I renamed everything etc. Big thanks !!

Comment: Your welcome. It definitely will work in your context too. Just make sure the references are all correct, including element names.